# Transform values without VBA but with Index and Match

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a solution without macros in excel for following problem:

There is a table containing ratings of a student for different time periods.

So the rating of the student with ID=1 was 1 from January to April and 3 from Mai to June.

Two other students had a constant ranking (6 and 9) from January to June

```
     | A   | B          | C          |D      |
  ---| ----|------------|------------|-------|
   1 | ID  | START      | END        |RANKING|
   2 | 1   | 01.01.2014 | 30.04.2014 |   1   |
   3 | 1   | 01.05.2014 | 30.06.2014 |   3   |
   4 | 2   | 01.01.2014 | 30.06.2014 |   6   |
   5 | 3   | 01.01.2014 | 30.06.2014 |   9   |
```

Next table contains IDs (y axis) and Months (x axis)

```
     | F   | G      | H      | I      | J      | K      | L      |
  ---| ----|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
   1 | ID  | 201401 | 201402 | 201403 | 201404 | 201405 | 201406 |
   2 | 1   |        |        |        |        |        |        |
   3 | 2   |        |        |        |        |        |        |
   4 | 3   |        |        |        |        |        |        |
```

And I wish to feel this second table like this:

```
| ID  | 201401 | 201402 | 201403 | 201404 | 201405 | 201406 |
| ----|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 1   |    1   |    1   |    1   |    1   |    3   |    3   |
| 2   |    6   |    6   |    6   |    6   |    6   |    6   |
| 3   |    9   |    9   |    9   |    9   |    9   |    9   |
```

I tried to use Index and Match, but without any good results because I haven't found a posibility to use IF (if (

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you're looking for with `SUMPRODUCT`

Given the layout you provided, this formula should work when put in `G2` and filled down and over

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A=$F2),--($B:$B<=G$1),--($C:$C>G$1),$D:$D)
```

That looks in column A for an ID matching F2, then for every one it finds of those:

- It checks the date in column B against the date in G1
- It checks the date in column C against the date in G1
- If all criteria match, it returns the value in Column D

This assumes you only have one entry for each period, otherwise it will sum them.

Also, you can use `SUMIFS`, it's a little less easy to read but I think it's slightly more efficient than `SUMPRODUCT` (I'm not positive, just anecdotal evidence from usage)

```
=SUMIFS($D:$D,$A:$A,"="&$F3,$B:$B,"<="&G$1,$C:$C,">"&G$1)
```

It does the exact same thing, just with different syntax.

Comment: What for a these double minus?

Comment: The double hyphen is converting a list of boolean (true, false) values to ZEROs and ONEs. Each hyphen acts as a negation. When you negate something, excel converts the underlying values to numbers and then reverses the SIGN. So `TRUE` becomes -1 and `FALSE` becomes 0. The second negation reverses this and leaves just numbers thus allowing SUMPRODUCT` to actually multiply instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. And thanks, your solution is working and is much easier to read than those with index and match

Comment: No problem! I edited my answer with another solution that may be slightly more efficient than `SUMPRODUCT` albeit slightly hard to read